# Pester testing an inlinescript of a powershell workflow

Tags: powershell, pester

I run the following test with Invoke-Pester. The 'function' tests fine but the 'workflow' fails. Is there any way for the test to see the calls within the InlineScript? Thanks.

```
BeforeAll {
    function TestFunction {
        Write-Host  "Executing function"
        Get-Host
    }

    workflow TestWorkflow {

        InlineScript {
            Write-Host  "Executing inlinescript"            
            Get-Host
        }
    }
}

Describe "Test-Workflow" {
    BeforeAll {
        Mock Get-Host { "Mocked Get-Host" }
    }
    
    Context 'test' {
        It 'workflow' {
            TestWorkflow
            Should -Invoke -Command Get-Host -Exactly 1
        }

        It 'function' {
            TestFunction
            Should -Invoke -Command Get-Host -Exactly 1
        }

    }
}
```

The test results:

```
[-] Test-Workflow.test.workflow 1.53s (1.53s|4ms)
 Expected Get-Host to be called 1 times exactly, but was called 0 times
 at Should -Invoke -Command Get-Host -Exactly 1, C:\Test-Workflow.Tests.ps1:25
 at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Test-Workflow.Tests.ps1:25
Executing function
Tests completed in 1.97s
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Comment: Add logging.  See : https://pester.dev/docs/usage/troubleshooting.  Since error says Get-Host was called 0 times the error must be happening be with either the Write-Host or Get-Host.  Probably the connection is not completing or authentication is failing.

Comment: I am running on localhost only, removing Write-Host doesn't affect the problem. If the error was within Get-Host I would think that would be counted as a call. I did replace Get-Host with Get-Date, same failure. Logging shows "Mock: Mock for Get-Host was invoked from block Process, resolving call history and behaviors." in the case of the 'function' It but this entry is missing from the 'workflow' It. I can only guess Mock is simply unable to detect calls in the InlineScript

Comment: Maybe following will help : https://pester.dev/docs/usage/mocking

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is not possible in workflows as they are executed in a separate process by Windows Workflow Foundation. Pester has no control or state in that process.